# Android - Use the Activity callback in a standard java class

Tags: android, callback, android-lifecycle, aar

I'm developing an .aar library and I really need to interact with the lifecycle of an activity (so the `callback` `onCreate()`, on `onResume()`, etc...) in a standard java class.
I tried a lot of things but nothing works.
Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: _I tried a lot of things_. What did you try?

Comment: I tried extending the Activity class (without istanciating an intent though), I tried getting a reference of the activity where my standard class will operate and use its callback but it didn't work either, finally tried some solutions I've seen on the Internet but now I don't rember them all.

Comment: @giuseppebrb can  you post some code?

Comment: @Krish I really don't think my code can be useful. I'd like to know the process that I should follow, my code will be almost certainly rewrite

Comment: @giuseppebrb you can use a interface to implement this requirement.

Comment: @Krish can you please explain me your hypothesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you need some thing like this,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * @Krish
 */

public class LifeCycleObserver {

    private LifeCycleObserver() {}

    private static LifeCycleObserver sLifeCycleObserver;

    public static LifeCycleObserver getInstance()
    {
        if (sLifeCycleObserver == null)
        {
            sLifeCycleObserver = new LifeCycleObserver();
        }

        return sLifeCycleObserver;
    }


    public static void init(Application application)
    {
        application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(sLifeCycleObserver.lifecycleCallbacks);
    }


    private Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks lifecycleCallbacks = new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

        }
    };

}
```

and use it like this in Application class,

import android.app.Application;

```
/**
 * Created by krish
 */

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        LifeCycleObserver.init(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this sould worked fine but this force the users of my library to import manually every callback that I define into their activites and I would to avoid this behaviour. So that's why I need to "take control" of their activities lifecycle in my standard class.

Comment: What about the users using your base activity class for the apps. and you should call this method in the baseactiviy? and force them to use you BaseActivity.

Comment: In this way they are forced to used an activity defined by me and not simply including my features... I really appreciate your effort but not even this solution seems me right

Comment: Can you describe , what is your exact requirement?What is your minimum API Level support.

Comment: I have updated the answer , but it will only work with API level 14 and above.

Comment: API Level 14 are fine! I'll try this, thank you so much!

Comment: @giuseppebrb Did you try my answer?

Comment: just tried and it worked! This could take me 10 steps forward in what I'm developing! thank you so much!